# Why is vtkClipPolyData is rendering very slowly in surface rendered output in vtk

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, vtk

I have the following codes to clip a model, but when I update the Plane to generate the new clipped surface it is very slow. Is there a way to make this faster? or is there another vtk class to perform faster?

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> clipPlane =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane>::New();
clipPlane->SetNormal(1, 1, 0);
clipPlane->SetOrigin(0.0, -10.0, 0.0 );

vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipPolyData> clipper = 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipPolyData>::New();
clipper->SetInputData( reader->GetOutput() );
clipper->SetClipFunction( clipPlane );
clipper->Update();
```

But I found no answer for this question.Any help would be appriciated
I have found that my problem is same as in the link that is given below.For reference use the below link

http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/is-vtkClipPolyData-slow-td5727625.html[1](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/is-vtkClipPolyData-slow-td5727625.html)

Comment: Hey, pressing `a` key for "actor", you can enter the standard `vtkRenderWindowInteractor` into the actor mode (explained here: https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInteractorStyle.html) . Have it a try: grab and move the actor around the clipping plane set via the mapper. You should see that it responds immediately.

Comment: I am using `vtkWin32RenderWindowInteractor`.Does your solution works in that?

Comment: It does, `r` for reset camera, `t` for trackball camera, `f` for flying into polygon position and so on. When the actor's transform changes (via interaction by mouse), the clip plane doesn't.

Comment: thanks .since I am new to vtk i will try

Comment: In the Visualization Toolkit popup window interactively via mouse; it opens when you do `vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderWindowInteractor > ia=vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();` `ia->SetRenderWindow( rw );` and `ia->Initialize(); ia->Start();` Hope that helps :)

Comment: Iam sorry for troubling.But i didnt understand your sugession "**Hey, pressing a key for "actor", you can enter the standard vtkRenderWindowInteractor into the actor mode (explained here: vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInteractorStyle.html) . Have it a try: grab and move the actor around the clipping plane set via the mapper. You should see that it responds immediately. – mainactual"**

Comment: added sample code for clipping. Interactor usage is perhaps out of topic at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you wish to achieve: `vtkClipPolyData` calculates a new geometry clipped with the `vtkImplicitFunction` provided. I guess you can write a "StrictlyPlaneClipPolyData" filter faster than the current one.

However, if rendering is the case, then you can (and should) let the shader do it. Simply as follows:

```
//vtkActor * actor;
actor->GetMapper()->AddClippingPlane( clipPlane );
```

After interaction then, perhaps, you apply the geometry filter only once.

*** EDIT ***

Sample code to demonstrate the performance:
[image: blender.org Monkey]

```
#include "vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h"
#include "vtkRenderer.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindow.h"
#include "vtkRenderer.h"
#include "vtkClipPolyData.h"
#include "vtkPolyDataMapper.h"
#include "vtkActor.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include "vtkPlane.h"
#include "vtkTransform.h"
#include "vtkMath.h"
#include "vtkProperty.h"
// performance counter in ms units
double ticks(void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER lg,f;
    if ( QueryPerformanceCounter( &lg ) && QueryPerformanceFrequency( &f ) )
        return 1000.0 * (double)lg.QuadPart/(double)f.QuadPart;
    else
        return (double)GetTickCount();
}
void ClipSample( void )
{
    vtkPolyData * monkey;
    // monkey is the Blender monkey courtesy of Blender.org 
    // @126 k vertices
    // make sure to transform the monkey into origin 

    // create render window
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderer > ren = vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderer >::New();
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderWindow > rw = vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderWindow >::New();
    rw->AddRenderer( ren );
    rw->SetSize( 1024,1024 );
    // create interactor used later
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkRenderWindowInteractor > ia = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    ia->SetRenderWindow( rw );
    ia->SetInteractorStyle(  vtkSmartPointer< vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera >::New() );
    ia->Initialize();

    // create clipper
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> plane = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> ::New();
    plane->SetNormal(0,0,1);
    plane->SetOrigin(0,0,0);

//#define SOFTWARE_CLIPPER

    // create mapper
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkPolyDataMapper > mapper = vtkSmartPointer< vtkPolyDataMapper >::New();
#ifdef SOFTWARE_CLIPPER
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkClipPolyData > clipper = vtkSmartPointer< vtkClipPolyData >::New();
    clipper->SetInputData( monkey );
    clipper->SetClipFunction( plane );
    mapper->SetInputConnection( clipper->GetOutputPort() );
#else
    mapper->SetInputData( monkey );
    mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane );
#endif

    // create actor
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkActor > actor = vtkSmartPointer< vtkActor >::New();
    actor->SetMapper( mapper );
    actor->GetProperty()->SetColor( 0.3, 1.0, 0.7 );

    // color back face to emphasize clipping
    vtkSmartPointer< vtkProperty > backface = vtkSmartPointer< vtkProperty > ::New();
    backface->SetColor(1,0,0);
    actor->SetBackfaceProperty( backface );

    ren->AddActor( actor );
    double delta = 20.0;

    double timeTotal=0.0;
    double count=0.0;
    for ( int i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        // make rotation axis
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> trf0=vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
        trf0->RotateZ( vtkMath::Random(-90,90) );
        trf0->RotateX( vtkMath::Random(-90,90) );
        trf0->RotateY( vtkMath::Random(-90,90) );
        const double * axis = trf0->TransformNormal(0,0,1);

        for ( double z=-180; z<180; z+=delta ) 
        {
            double time = ticks();
            // rotate the clipper around its axis
            double normal[3];
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> trf=vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
            trf->RotateWXYZ( z, axis );
            plane->SetNormal( trf->TransformNormal(0,0,1) );
            ia->Render();
            time = ticks()-time;
            timeTotal+=time;
            count+=1.0;
            Sleep( 30 ); // too fast otherwise
        }
    }
#ifdef SOFTWARE_CLIPPER
    std::cout << "Software clipper: ";
#else
    std::cout << "Hardware clipper: ";
#endif
    std::cout << "time per iteration " << timeTotal/count << " ms" << std::endl;
    ia->Start(); // start interactor finally: use 'C','A' etc. for changing interaction modes
}
```

Comparison of hardware and software clipper ( Windows 10, Intel i5 8th gen, VTK8.1):

```
Software clipper: time per iteration 76.5701 ms

Hardware clipper: time per iteration 1.63613 ms
```

Comment: I tried like this 
`vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> clipPlane =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane>::New();
clipPlane->SetNormal(1, 1, 0);
clipPlane->SetOrigin(0.0, -10.0, 0.0 );

vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipPolyData> clipper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipPolyData>::New();
clipper->SetInputData( reader->GetOutput() );
clipper->SetClipFunction( clipPlane );
clipper->Update();
mapper->SetInput(clipper->GetOutput());
actor->SetMapper(mapper);
actor->GetMapper()->AddClippingPlane( clipPlane);
renderer->AddActor(actor);`
But no improvement

Comment: @Ria that way, you do the clipping twice. Simply connect the `reader->GetOutput()` to the mapper (be sure to call `reader->Update()` doing so or use the `SetInputConnection` alternative.

Comment: Like this?                 `vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> clipPlane =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane>::New();
clipPlane->SetNormal(1, 1, 0);
clipPlane->SetOrigin(0.0, -10.0, 0.0 );

mapper->SetInput(reader->GetOutput());
reader->Update();
   
actor->SetMapper(mapper);
actor->GetMapper()->AddClippingPlane( plane1);
renderer->AddActor(aActor); 
renderWindow->Render();
interactor->Initialize();`

Comment: @Ria yes like this. Done that way though, I would have guessed the `vtkClipPolyData` cost is negligible compared to reading the file from the disk. If you repeat the clipping, then it is of course slow.

Comment: @Ria well, initialization of renderer and reading will take some time also

Comment: Thanks sir.I didn't get the results much faster but the speed has increased than before.Thanks for helping

Comment: one more doubt.How can  i use`InsideOutOn`function in this clipping?

Comment: @Ria for plane, just flipping the normal (multiply by -1 elementwise) makes the same effect

Comment: :) thanks.can i incorporate both positive and negative clipping in one actor

Comment: @Ria hardware clipper support maximum of 6 planes, which you can combine of course in anyway (typical being clipping by cube sides)

Comment: Ya.I mean can i show both clipping planes in same 3d output? For that shall i need to assign planes seperately to mapper like this  `mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane1 );   mapper->AddClippingPlane( plane2 );  ` ?

Comment: @Ria like that, each mapper (and actor thereby) can have up to 6, which you set up by AddClippingPlane (or better to keep book yourself using vtkPlaneCollection version)